# Disambiguate Function calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I am working through Learn Ruby The Hard Way and came across something intriguing in [exercise 49](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex49.html).

In `parser.rb` I have a function named `skip(word_list, word_type)` at the top level, which is used to skip through unrequited words (such as stop words) in user input. It is not encapsulated in a class or module. As per the exercise I have to write a unit test for the parser.

This is my code for the Unit Tests:

```
require "./lib/ex48/parser"
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestGame < Minitest::Test

  def test_skip()
    word_list = [['stop', 'from'], ['stop', 'the'], ['noun', 'west']]

    assert_equal(skip(word_list, 'stop'), nil)
    assert_equal(skip([['noun', 'bear'], ['verb', 'eat'], ['noun', 'honey']], 'noun'), nil)
  end
end
```

However, when I run `rake test TESTOPTS="-v"` from the command line, these particular tests are skipped. This seems to be because there is a clash with the `skip` method in the Minitest module because they run perfectly after I change the name to `skip_words`.

Can someone please explain what is going on here exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Top level functions" are actually methods too, in particular they are private instance methods on Object (there's some funkiness around the `main` object but that's not important here)

However minitest's Test class also has a `skip` method and since the individual tests are instance methods on a subclass of  `Test` you end up calling that skip instead.

There's not a very simple way of dealing with this - unlike some languages there is no easy way of saying that you want to call a particular superclass' implementation of something

Other than renaming your method, you'll have to pick an alternative way of calling it eg:

```
Object.new.send(:skip, list, type)
Object.instance_method(:skip).bind(self).call(list, type)
```

Of course you can wrap this in a helper method for your test or even redefine skip for this particular `Test` subclass (although that might lead to some head scratching the day someone tries to call minitest's `skip`.